# Create new instance of Image in C# using SixLabors.ImageSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagesharp

I am trying to create new instance of Image class with SixLabors.Imagesharp but I got error. The system I work with used the old ImageSharp and We want to renew nuget packages and use SixLabors.ImageSharp instead.

The code used to be like this:
OLD Code with ImageSharp:

```
var resultImage = new Image<Rgba32>(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight);
```

The new code I try to write with SixLabors.ImageSharp is exactly the same but this time I got the massage:

```
Severity Code Description   Project File Linem Suppression State
Error CS0315 The type 'SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.Rgba32' cannot be used as type parameter 'TPixel' in the generic type or method 'Image<TPixel>'. There is no boxing conversion from 'SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.Rgba32' to '?'.
```

I tried a lot of other ways to create a new Image but I failed. Do you have any idea how I can create new Image using SixLabors.Imagesharp?

Comment: Your code works fine for me using the latest build on nuget, 1.0.0-rc0001. Which version of ImageSharp do you have?

Comment: I use same version too. You can build without any problem? @Rup

Comment: Yes, it builds and runs without any problem. I tested with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and 4.8, and .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: @ParhamGitijah You should now mark an answer

Answer (score 9):

The namespace for the pixel format has changed so your code is missing an import.

```cs
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
```

The following code compiles and runs for [1.0.0-rc0001](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp/1.0.0-rc0001)

```cs
using (var image = new Image<Rgba32>(1000, 1000))
{
    // Do something
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image-1.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_1__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Documentation](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image-1.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_1__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_), the constructor does not take the Generic  so modify as below and try.

```
var resultImage = new Image(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight);
```

EDIT:
Corrected the Documentation Link. Thanks @James

Comment: I tried but it doesnt work. Got this error:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0144 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Image' ..NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: The constructor you've linked to is protected, so no that can't be used (even if the non-generic Image wasn't abstract).

Comment: Always good to point at the docs. Correct link is [here](https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image-1.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_1__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: Image is an abstract class so this doesn't work.
https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.html